# How does R know not to use the old 'f'?

Tags: r

Into the R console, type:

```
#First code snippet
x <- 0
x <- x+1
x
```

You'll get '1'. That makes sense: the idea is that the 'x' in 'x+1' is the current value of x, namely 0, and this is used to compute the value of x+1, namely 1, which is then shoveled into the container x. So far, so good.

Now type:

```
#Second code snippet
f <- function(n) {n^2}
f <- function(n) {if (n >= 1) {n*f(n-1)} else {1}}
f(5)
```

You'll get '120', which is 5 factorial.

I find this perplexing. Following the logic of the first code snippet, we might expect the 'f' in the expression

```
if (n >= 1) {n*f(n-1)} else {1}
```

to be interpreted as the current value of f, namely

```
function(n) {n^2}
```

Following this reasoning, the value of f(5) should be 5*(5-1)^2 = 80. But that's not what we get.

> **Question.** What's really going on here? How does R know not to use the old 'f'?

Comment: I would imagine once we're inside `f ,- function` any `f` means that `f` i.e. we have immediately lost the previous function

Comment: Once you reassigned something to the (global) symbol `f`, the previous object bound to `f` is lost.

Comment: @Roland, you didn't read the question, did you?

Comment: More specifically, R doesn't bind symbols to values inside a function definition until the function is run. So when you redefine `f` the second time, R doesn't attempt to bind the `f` used inside the function to anything. When `f` is run, R then tries to find something called `f` and find itself.

Comment: @goblin you didn't understand my comment, did you? You should study what happens when a function is called in R and and what are the scoping rules. The [language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) is helpful here.

Comment: @goblin Do you know where the 120 comes from?

Comment: @Roland, hmm okay. I guess I'm not understanding your comment then.

Comment: A little experiment. Try `foo <- function(x) bar(x)`. What? How can this not result in an error, when `bar` is not even defined? An error happens only at actual lookup, for example when you try `foo(1)`. Now define a function `bar` in the global environment. `foo` will work just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> we might expect the 'f' in the expression
>
> ```
> if (n >= 1) {n*f(n-1)} else {1}
> ```
>
> to be interpreted as the current value of f

— Yes, we might expect that. And we would be correct.

But what is the “current value of `f`”? Or, more precisely, what is “current”?

**“Current” is when the function is executed**, not when it is defined. That is, by the time you execute `f(5)`, it has already been redefined. So now the execution enters the function, looks up *inside the function* what `f` refers to — and also finds the current (= new) definition, not the old one.

In other words: the objects associated with names are looked up when they are actually accessed. And inside a function this means that names are accessed when the function is executed, not when it’s defined.

The same is true for *all* objects. Let’s say `f` is using a global object that’s not a function:

```
n = 5
f = function() n ^ 2

n = 1
f() # = 1
```

---

To understand the difference between your first and second example, consider the following case which involved functions, yet behaves like your first case (i.e. it uses the “old” value of `f`).

To make the example work, we need a little helper: a function that modifies other functions. In the following, `twice` is a function which takes a function as an argument and returns *a new function*. That new function is the same as the old function, only it runs twice when invoked:

```
twice = function (original_function) {
    force(original_function)
    function (...) {
        original_function(original_function(...))
    }
}
```

To illustrate what `twice` does, let’s invoke it on an example function:

```
plus1 = function (n) n + 1
plus2 = twice(plus1)
plus2(3) # = 5
```

Neat — R allows us to handle functions like any other object!

Now let’s modify your `f`:

```
f = function(n) {n^2}
f = twice(f)
f(5) # 625
```

… and here we have it: in the statement `f = twice(f)`, the second `f` refers to the *current* (= old) definition. Only after that line does `f` refer to the new, modified function.

Comment: @goblin Well sure, but “at the moment of redefinition” only concerns those things that need to be known for the definition of the function, not for its execution (i.e. nothing inside it). If we defined the new `f` in terms of the old `f`, this old `f` would indeed be used. However, it’s hard to find good examples of that because functions that modify other functions are rare. I’ll try finding a concise example.

Comment: For a deeper understanding of this I recommend Hadley Wickhams "Advanced R". Take a look at the dynamic lookup section: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html.

Comment: I wonder if the fundamental behavior is easier to grasp when removed from functions: `n <- 5; f <- function() {n^2}; n <- 1; f()` returns 1 not 25. The value of `n` in `f` is determined at runtime, not at the point of function creation.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. @joran, Konrad, suppose I want to define a function `f <- function() {a*b}` but with a modification so that the 'b' used is the current value of b at the moment of definition, not the moment of execution. Is this possible?

Comment: @goblin No, that’s not possible in R. What you can do (and what people usually do) is copy the value and use the copied value in the function: `b_copy = b`, `f = function() a * b_copy`. Personally I wrap the whole thing into a `local` block to avoid other people accidentally messing with my `b_copy`: https://gist.github.com/klmr/546f32924f18060f3b8a9854fee29816

Comment: Even shorter: you can run `f <- function() {n^2}` even if n is not yet defined. Only actually calling `f()` results in `Error: object n not found`. And `f` will run fine when `n` is defined afterwards.

Comment: @antoine-sac True, and this was the example I initially wrote. However, this is actually a slightly unrelated matter. There are other languages where a name needs to be defined before it’s used, yet redefining the value will nevertheless use the new value. This is the case for instance in C++: your example wouldn’t compile, yet declaring `n` before `f` and then (re)defining it later works as in R.

Comment: @goblin you can use a closure: `times_b_generator <- function() {my_b <- b ; function(a) a*my_b} ;

b <- 5 ; 

times_b <- times_b_generator() ;

b <- 1 ;

times_b(2)` will yield `10` (the value of b is captured in the closure environment when `times_b` is created). Adapt this to your use case. Or more likely, rethink your problem :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Technically, I think you could alter the environment of `f` to be one that included only a value for `b`, then `f` would always find that `b` first even if `b` is reassigned in the global environment.

Comment: I guess you can do something like `b = 5; f <- eval(substitute(function() b, as.list(.GlobalEnv)))` whick works like `rm(b); f()` but that seems like a bad approach. Whoa, had no idea `local()` was a thing (looking at comments above); I guess I will use that.

Comment: @joran That’s exactly what my `local` code does — I just made it more readable by renaming the variable but there’s no need to: https://gist.github.com/klmr/546f32924f18060f3b8a9854fee29816#file-test2-r … apart from that you could obviously inspect and manipulate `body(f)` and `substitute` `b` with its value: `body(f) = do.call(substitute, list(body(f), list(b = b)))`. ;-)

Comment: Ah, I see. I got off in the weeds a bit.

Comment: @antoine-sac, to be clear, I'm not working on a problem - I was just thinking about some abstract stuff and it occurred to me that the second code snippet should cause R to misbehave. When I typed it into the console and found that, in fact, it doesn't misbehave -- well, I was slightly impressed, and very confused. I get it now, though. Joran's example in the comments here is what really cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example illustrating my comment on Konrad's excellent answer:

```
a <- 2
f <- function() a*b

e <- new.env()
assign("b",5,e)
environment(f) <- e

> f()
[1] 10

b <- 10

> f()
[1] 10
```

So we've manually altered the environment for `f` so that it always first looks in `e` for `b`. Theoretically, one could even lock that binding `?lockBinding` to make sure it never changes without throwing an error.

This sort of thing could get complicated, though, as in general you'd want to make sure that you set the parent environment of `e` correctly based on where the function `f` is actually being created. In this example `f` is created in the global environment, but if `f` were being created inside another function, you'd want `e`'s parent environment to reflect that.